making hole mesh to solid mesh

I have two layers and I need to fill between them with mesh.

Is the topology (i.e. connectivity between vertices) the same on both layers ? Or are they completely decorrelated ?

it is not the same, they have different topology.

To clarify, in Blender there is no such thing as an "inside 3D mesh" the kind you have in CFD or FEM softwares for example. A "volume" is just a closed (manifold) surface. So, do you try to make the missing surface that will be connecting the boundary of both layers ? This is not related to extrusion, but more like a Bridge Edge Loops operation.
